# Why i am getting error when running C# project with VS Express 2012 about MySQL connection that could not found

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using in C# connection code to MySql database

in the header I have:
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

I installed the MySql connector for .Net
I added reference to MySql.data for the project but still
it giving me error.

Pleaselet me know what is missing ?

[image: This is the VS 2012 project window and error message when running the project]

Comment: Look at the warning below. It explains a lot

Comment: @IbrahimShendy it is the contrary. He uses the connector version 6.1 and this requires NET 4.5.2 but the current NET version is 4.0. So he should change the NET version to 4.5.2 or install the connector version 6.9 (See [MySql/NET Versions table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html))

Comment: Many thanks for the answers, i changed  the project settings .net framework version to 4.5.2 and it run without error